# Load View from Plugin without Embedding it as Resources in nopCommerce

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce

We're working on a Plugin development where we need to have to override theme view files from within the Plugin. For example, consider a Category Product Listing Page, where instead of theme View file we need to provide its view from within a Plugin view files.

However, this is very limiting, as it works only if we embed the resource while building the Plugin. So that way, it is not possible to customize View File, but we can not embed View file in the Plugin becasue we need that View files can be customized as per custom requirement of the project.. but core Plugin functions remains the same.

So basically need to call the View file in the Plugin without embeding it.

I have viewed few plugins that are doing it this way, but I'm unable to figure out how to do that in my plugin. Any idea how to build plugin this way that allows to change modifications in View files.

Just a note that we're working on nopCommerce 2.65 version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this link: http://coding-in.net/mvc-3-organize-your-partial-views/. Basically you just need to create a custom view engine and tell ASP.Net to find the view in a special path. :)

Comment: Hmm.. your answer is correct. We will be working on this soon.

Comment: Cool thing. Good luck implementing! :D

Comment: please update the link in the the post , `Server not found`.